Comparison of macros fails
I am new to LaTex and have been given a problem by my colleagues. They define a document type in a TeX file (e.g. 'svvr', 'srs', ...). This external definition corresponds to lines 4 and 5 in my example code (MWE 2).
Now I should use this external definition in my TeX file to decide which document-dependent processing should take place. To do this, I have written an MWE to test the selection.
My test code originally comes from the Internet and compares the job name with a given string (e.g. "{\detokenize{svvr}"). I named my TeX file "svvr.tex" to be able to make the comparison with \jobname.
My problem now is that when I compare with \jobname (MWE 1), the selection works correctly.
\documentclass{article}

% Own TeX file:
\begin{document}
    \edef\docTypeExt{\jobname}
    % Specify which document type is to be handled: 'svvr', 'srs', ...
    \edef\docTypeSvvr{\detokenize{svvr}} 
    \edef\docTypeSrs{\detokenize{srs}}

    \textbf{\jobname} 
    \textbf{\docShortcut}
    \textbf{\docTypeSvvr}
    \textbf{\docTypeSrs}
    \newline
    
    \ifx\docTypeExt\docTypeSvvr
        true
    \else
        false: \\
        \jobname \\
        \docShortcut \\
        \docTypeSvvr
    \fi
\newline

    \ifx\docTypeExt\docTypeSrs
        true
    \else
        false: \\
        \jobname \\
        \docShortcut \\
        \docTypeSrs
    \fi

\end{document}

But if I compare to the external definition by my colleagues (MWE 2), the comparison fails.
\documentclass{article}

% Given code, defined in included TeX file: 'svvr', 'srs', ...
\newcommand { \docpropPTdocShortcut } {svvr}    % Define document type here!
\gdef\docShortcut{\docpropPTdocShortcut}

% Own TeX file:
\begin{document}
    \edef\docTypeExt{\docShortcut}
    % Specify which document type is to be handled: 'svvr', 'srs', ...
    \edef\docTypeSvvr{\detokenize{svvr}} 
    \edef\docTypeSrs{\detokenize{srs}}

    \textbf{\jobname} 
    \textbf{\docShortcut}
    \textbf{\docTypeSvvr}
    \textbf{\docTypeSrs}
    \newline
    
    \ifx\docTypeExt\docTypeSvvr
        true
    \else
        false: \\
        \jobname \\
        \docShortcut \\
        \docTypeSvvr
    \fi
\newline

    \ifx\docTypeExt\docTypeSrs
        true
    \else
        false: \\
        \jobname \\
        \docShortcut \\
        \docTypeSrs
    \fi

\end{document}

How must the selection be structured so that it also works with the external definition?
I have modified the definitions, but all attempts so far have failed.

It is not clear what exactly your end goal is here. Perhaps there are better ways. Often one have to be cery careful with these comparisons, especially if non-ascii gets involved

Note that the first MWE does not even compile

MWE2 works if you remove the detokenize.

It works now!
Thank you so much @daleif!

Within your first example a control sequence \docShortcut occurs. But it is not defined.

If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every question. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

Every character token delivered by \jobname is of category 12(other). Exception: Spaces (code point number 32 both in ASCII and in Unicode) are of category 10(space). Same with character tokens delivered by \detokenize.
However, the character tokens that with your second example go into the replacement text of \docpropPTdocShortcut are not delivered by \jobname or \detokenize but come into being due to TeX reading and tokenizing things from the .tex-input file. Hereby another category code régime is applied so that many character tokens that come into being this way have a category that differs from 12(other). E.g., character tokens denoting letters of the alphabet coming into being this way usually have category 11(letter).
Thus a control sequence token \docTypeSvvr or \docTypeSrs, whose replacement text only consists of character tokens that come from \jobname or \detokenize and therefore are character tokens of category 12(other) or spaces of category 10(space), has a meaning which differs from the meaning of a control sequence \docTypeExt where the same characters got tokenized with category 11(letter).
Thus \ifx-comparison with your second example routes to the \else-branch.
With your second example you can either omit \detokenize when defining \docTypeSvvr/\docTypeSrs or apply \detokenize or \@onelevel@sanitize when defining \docTypeExt.
\newline, which causes LaTeX to continue typesetting the paragraph , but beginning another line of the paragraph, trailed by an empty line, which causes LaTeX to end the current paragraph, seems sort of redundant to me: You get the vertical \baselineskip from \newline and the vertical \parskip if that is not zero. If vertical \parskip is zero and in some places you wish some vertical skip between paragraphs, don't abuse \newline for this but use \vspace or \addvspave or \vskip or \smallskip or \medskip or \bigskip.
\newcommand { \docpropPTdocShortcut } {svvr}, where \docpropPTdocShortcut after tokenization is preceded by a space token, is not good practice. If not in ExplSyntax, where spaces would be ignored already at the time of tokenizing things, do:
\newcommand{\docpropPTdocShortcut}{svvr}.
With the example below the \detokenize-route is taken so you can safely compare to macros whose replacement text is made up by the expansion of \jobname if you like.
\documentclass{article}


% Given code, defined in included TeX file: 'svvr', 'srs', ...
%% (In case the TeX file in question does not produce text/a chapter of the document, 
%%  \input might be a better choice than \include ...)

\newcommand{\docpropPTdocShortcut}{svvr}% Define document type here!
\gdef\docShortcut{\docpropPTdocShortcut}

% Own TeX file:
\begin{document}
  \edef\docTypeExt{\docShortcut}%%
  \edef\docTypeExt{\detokenize\expandafter{\docTypeExt}}%%
  %\csname @onelevel@sanitize\endcsname\docTypeExt
  %-----------------------------------------------------------------  
  % Specify which document type is to be handled: 'svvr', 'srs', ...
  \edef\docTypeSvvr{\detokenize{svvr}}%%
  \edef\docTypeSrs{\detokenize{srs}}%%

  \noindent
  \verb|\jobname|: \texttt{\jobname}\\
  \verb|\docShortcut|: \texttt{\meaning\docShortcut}\\
  \verb|\docTypeExt|: \texttt{\meaning\docTypeExt}\\
  \verb|\docTypeSvvr|: \texttt{\meaning\docTypeSvvr}\\
  \verb|\docTypeSrs|: \texttt{\meaning\docTypeSrs}

  \vskip\baselineskip

  \noindent
  \ifx\docTypeExt\docTypeSvvr
      true
  \else
      false:\\
      \jobname\\
      \docShortcut\\
      \docTypeSvvr
  \fi

  \vskip\baselineskip

  \noindent
  \ifx\docTypeExt\docTypeSrs
      true
  \else
      false:\\
      \jobname\\
      \docShortcut\\
      \docTypeSrs
  \fi
\end{document}

